# Auto-submitting HTML form to self PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have this simple code:

```
<?
if (isset($_POST["phpinfo"])) phpinfo(); else echo "you haven't chosen what to do yet";
?>
<h1>Test page 1</h1>
<form method="post" action="">
<select>
<option>Choose what to do</option>
<option value='phpinfo'>phpinfo();</option></select></form>
```

The problem is that if I use JavaScript (onChange="this.form.submit()") to auto-submit the post data it doesn't submit but if I use a submit button it does submit to self.

```
<input type="submit" name='phpinfo' id="phpinfo">
```

My question is, what do I have to do so I can have an auto-submitting drop down list that submits POST data to self?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try giving the `<form>` an `id=""` and using `document.getElementById().submit()` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your select needs to be named.  The select name is what's returned to PHP, and its value will be the value of the option selected.

```
<select name="performaction">
    <option value="phpinfo">phpinfo ()</option>
</select>

if ($_POST [performaction] == 'phpinfo')
{
    phpinfo ();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

if($_POST['txtVal'] != "") {
            echo "Form Submited";
       }
?>


 <form method="post" action="">
    <select name="txtVal" onchange="this.form.submit();">
        <option>Choose what to do</option>
        <option value='phpinfo'>phpinfo();</option></select>
 </form>
```

Hope it will works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
//add a name to form
<form method="post" action="" name="some_name">

//then on your select's onchange function do:
document.forms['some_name'].submit();
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['selctVal']) && $_POST['selctVal']!="" )
{

    echo "Form Submited =><br/>";

    echo  "Form Submited =>".$_POST['selctVal'];
}
else
{
    echo "you haven't chosen what to do yet";

}
?>


 <form method="post" action="" name="anyformname">
    <select name="selctVal" onchange="document.anyformname.submit();">
        <option>Choose what to do</option>
        <option value='<?php echo phpinfo();?>'>phpinfo();</option>
    </select>
 </form>
```